# Recenter heatmap.2 in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I used following code to generate a heatmap using heatmap.2 of R. key="F" gets rid of color key at the top. However the plot does not rescale leaving a blank space on the place previously occupied by the colour key. How do I recenter the plot by getting rid of the blank space at the top?

```
dImp_heatmap <- heatmap.2(dSet_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(20), dendrogram="none",trace="none", key="F",margins=c(1,8),colsep=c(1:6),rowsep=(1:62),sepwidth=c(0.05,0.05), sepcolor="white", cellnote=round(dSet_matrix,digits=2),notecol="black",notecex=0.7,scale="column")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `?heatplot.2` carefully, you'll see at the bottom of the list of arguments the following:

> lmat, lhei, lwid   visual layout: position matrix, column height,
>   column width. See below for details

And the details are:

> This layout can be overriden by specifiying appropriate values for
>   lmat, lwid, and lhei. lmat controls the relative postition of each
>   element, while lwid controls the column width, and lhei controls the
>   row height. See the help page for layout for details on how to use
>   these arguments.

So for example:

```
data(mtcars)
 x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
 rc <- rainbow(nrow(x), start=0, end=.3)
 cc <- rainbow(ncol(x), start=0, end=.3)

 ##
 ## demonstrate the effect of row and column dendrogram options
 ##
 gplots:::heatmap.2(x,key = FALSE,dendrogram = "row",lhei = c(0.05,0.95))
```

[image]

and I imagine the setting `lwid` would behave similarly. Although I should add that if you include both dendrograms, then the space in the upper left is necessary to make room for the dendrograms.

Comment: thanks, this is great! I first tried with `lhei = c(0, 1)`, but until the first element is below `0.03` it throws a `figure margins too large` error. this an issue with `heatmap.2`